# how can I use array in place of name value pair in a function

Tags: arrays, name-value

In the below code how can I use options array which is passed as a argument to `drawOval`

```
drawOval=function(options) {
    $triangle = new Triangle({
        // how can I use options array here
        // the format it accept is top:450,
        // left:500,width:200
    });
};
opt = new Array(
    top: 450,
    left: 500,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: 'rgb(204,0,107)'
);
drawOval(opt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I need an object not array.

```
opt= {
    top:100,
    left:200,
    width:200,
    height:200,
    fill:'rgb(12,0,107)'
}
drawOval(opt);
```